# Get a set of the next 7 given days

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I allow teachers to set schedules for days they're working. Saved in the DB with their week days 0..6. Now what I want to achieve is to give a method a date, often todays date and retrieve the next 7 days they'll be able to work. Take note that for example if their `TimeSlot` only have a `week_day` column stored as `1` then the 7 next Mondays should be retrieved.

If it's Mondays and Wednesdays then they'll be returned until 7 days have been stored and returned.

Do anybody have experience in how I might handle this. I struggeling with how to find a good solution to iterate over dates.